# Carriage return symbol is removed from XML using OPENXML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing, openxml

It looks like SQL Server removes `\r` characters when parsing XML. So when my stored procedure receives values in xml for saving, all line breaks are represented as `\n` instead of `\r\n.`

Is there any way I can force SQL Server to not remove `\r` characters? In the sample below `Node1` value doesn't contain `\r` symbols.

```
    DECLARE @hDoc int
    DECLARE @Xml nvarchar(MAX) 
    SET @Xml = N'<Root><Node1><![CDATA[' + nchar(13) + nchar(10) + N'Some ' + nchar(13) + nchar(10) + N' Value]]></Node1></Root>'
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @Xml

    SELECT 
        Node1
        ,convert(varbinary(max),Node1) -- Contains 0A00 in the start instead of 0D0A,
        ,charindex(nchar(13),Node1)
    FROM
        OPENXML(@hDoc, N'/Root', 2) WITH (Node1 NVARCHAR(MAX))

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Output:
 [image]

@PJB suggested to use [XQuery nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345122(v=SQL.90).aspx) instead. But this doesn't helps. I tried to run query below and got the same result.

```
    DECLARE @xml xml
    SET @xml = convert(xml, N'<Root><Node1><![CDATA[' + nchar(13) + nchar(10) + N'Some ' + nchar(13) + nchar(10) + N' Value]]></Node1></Root>')

    declare @Node1 nvarchar(30)
    select @Node1 = node.value('.', 'nvarchar(30)')
    from @xml.nodes('/Root/Node1') as doc(node)

    SELECT 
        @Node1
        ,convert(varbinary(max),@Node1) -- Contains 0A00 in the start instead of 0D0A,
        ,charindex(nchar(13),@Node1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Carriage return symbol is removed from XML

This is the correct behavior according the XML spec on [End-of-Line Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends).

> the XML processor MUST behave as if it normalized all line breaks in
>   external parsed entities (including the document entity) on input,
>   before parsing, by translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA
>   and any #xD that is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character.

You could try to use a [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to get the carriage-return back.

```
select @Node1 = replace(node.value('.', 'nvarchar(30)'), nchar(10), nchar(13)+nchar(10))
from @xml.nodes('/Root/Node1') as doc(node)
```

Comment: Okay, this works for me.
I'm only concerned that database-level replacement doesn't contemplate the operating system environment for line breaks and also goes against the standard.
Perhaps it is better to solve it in a business or even customer layer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is better to solve it in a business or even customer layer, so as not to alter the standard applied in the database.
For example, if you have an application in the NET Framework it might be like this, when retrieving the values it would be possible to apply an appropriate replacement:

For Windows.Forms: Replace solitary LF.

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Line 1\r\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4",  @"(?<!\r)\n(?!\r)", Environment.NewLine);
```

For HTML: Replace the combinations you consider, by your preferred line break.

```
var result = "Line 1\r\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4".Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

The look-around pattern idea was taken from:

[Replace only one char not preceded or followed by X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986595/replace-one-character-but-not-two-in-a-string/32986717#32986717)